# Cut Tibble by group and merge it as columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

just a quick question. How can I cut my data by group (i.e. by year) and attach them as columns? All groups have the same length.

this is what I have now:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   year   sex
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000     1
2  2000     2
3  2001     1
4  2001     2
5  2002     1
6  2002     2
```

And I want it like this.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  year1  sex1 year2  sex2 year3  sex3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000     1  2001     1  2002     1
2  2000     2  2001     2  2002     2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `group_split` followed by `bind_cols`.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  group_split() %>% 
  bind_cols()
```

However, I would suggest not to do this: the resulting data format is quite hard to work with.

Comment: thank you that did it. I know that its an uncomfortable format, but its just for a small analysis.

Comment: Small remark - you can just do `group_split(year)`.